# Default number of digits after decimal in Windows

Tags: windows, vba, microsoft-access, regional-settings

I am exporting a database from Access to a CSV, and I was (finally) able to get more than two decimals to transfer after changing my [Windows Region settings](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=33763) settings to make 9 decimals the default. Is there any way to get 10 decimals? Is there a registry key or something I need to change?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202 - how many digits have you got stored in the database? The way to get those out should NOT depend on the regional settings.

Comment: @Hannu at least 10, when exporting the table to text, it seems to depend only on region settings.

Answer (score 1):

Check your csv file data (open with notepad or wordpad). I bet you will see all he digits you have in the database.

Excel should be able to display upwards some 16 decimals, filling in "0" for those that are not available or has no value.

Simple way to determine the limit

- Pick a cell, type "0.12345678901234567890" in it (assuming you use
  decimal POINT, change the point to a COMMA if necessary).
- Press ENTER and
- move back the cursor to the cell

... check the formula bar.
You should see e.g. "0.123456789012346" - meaning maximum 16 decimals retained

*(note: in reality it is more likely to be 16 digit precision, that is; also the integer digits count, if you have five there, there is only 11 decimals max).*


To DISPLAY all of them, set the DISPLAY-format
 - Mark all cells you wish to see the decimals in
 - hold CTRL and hit 1 (the digit ONE)
 - find the word "Number" and click on it
 - having done that, you should see "Decimals", adjust for your needs.
 - Click "OK"

Adjust column width wide enough so that all decimals can be shown;
 - Click the square left of "A" and just above "1" (column and row indexes)
 - Move the mouse pointer above the |-bar between A and B column indexes
 - Make the pointer be precisely over the bar, and it will turn into a
   double arrow
 - Double click the bar.

*All this typed from memory, I use LibreOffice Calc at home, details differ.*

Comment: Nice memory, but opening the csv in Excel has my data truncated it to 2 decimals

Comment: Click in one of the cells having a number; still only two decimals shown? How about loading the csv file into Notepad or any other editor, how many decimals do you see there?

Comment: If it’s showing only 2 decimal places then use the Excel decimal feature to show more decimal places if the value is 0 then your data is truncated at the source

Comment: as explained at `DISPLAY` above.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it is being truncated at the source, that's what this question aims to address.

Comment: You said the default number of decimals for your region was 9 but you indicated it was 2 in your comment.  Provide some screenshots